# Escape HTML on ExtJS application generally?

Tags: php, html, extjs, extjs4

I have already develop ExtJS application that application has more than 200 grids.
Some of grid have <> like HTML. My grid can't view HTML So i change Server side function(common get function) as `htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES);`

After that grid can view HTML value like

problem is when rowediting mode view value as encode value(`&lt;start`)

note: this happen every form, grid-rowediting,

i try to override every input filed as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456630/what-is-the-best-way-to-escape-html-on-extjs-application-generally) but that is not work for me

```
launch: function() {
    panel = Ext.create('me_project.view.me_panel', {renderTo: 'form'});
    Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
        setValue: function(val) {
            val = Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(val);
            return this.callParent([val]);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The htmlDecode function only decodes the `< > & '` symbols as shown in documentation http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.util.Format.html.
You can try setting the `autoEncode: true` property as shown in http://all-docs.info/extjs4/docs/api/Ext.grid.Editing.html.
To decode something that is html encoded with jquery you can use 
`val = $('<\div>').html(val).text();`
With javascript you can use 
`var textArea = document.createElement("textarea"); textArea.innerHTML =val; val = textArea.value;`

Comment: that is every hard to do go every filed and change get value method now. and ill hope ExtJs solution not Jquery anyway thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added a few other solutions.

Comment: @moishe thanks for `autoEncode`. Mixing jquery and ExtJs should always be avoided in my opinion.